# Apache + PHP: how to change the value of $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] in apache?

Tags: php, apache

for example, i have `mysite.com` and `beta.mysite.com`. both point to the same index file using the `virtualHost` directive. what will i do in the apache conf so that when i access the `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']`, the value would still be `mysite.com`?

this should be flexible that only the `beta` would be removed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe you could use a ServerAlias in your VirtualHost directive, and use only one VirtualHost directive:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName mysite.com
  ServerAlias beta.mysite.com
  ...
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 4):

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#usecanonicalname

Try this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName mysite.com
  ServerAlias beta.mysite.com

  UseCanonicalName On
</VirtualHost>
```

I'm assuming you have 1 VH, and not: 1 for each site (since they are the same site).

Restart apache after.